# getX() and getY() returning a different value in OnClickListener

Tags: java, android

I currently have a GridView setup that adds a TextView on click using the getX() and getY() of the cell onClick. When I tried to move this away from the OnClickListener, the value returned for the cellView's getX() and getY() values is always 0.0 instead of the value that is given in the OnClick Interface in OnclickListener. How can I get the getX() I am getting in the onClickListener outside of the listener?

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View cellView;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    cellView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_calendar, parent, false);

    TextView textView = (TextView) cellView.findViewById(R.id.calendar_date);
    textView.setText("" + dateArrayList.get(position).getDate());


    System.out.println(cellView.getX() + " / " + cellView.getY());      //Returns 0

    cellView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View view) {

            float buffer = bar1.getY();
            System.out.println(cellView.getX() + " / " + cellView.getY());          //Returns actual Location
            addText(cellView.getX() + 15, cellView.getY() + buffer, "Test String"); 

        }


});

public void addText(float x, float y, String textName) {

    TextView mTextView = new TextView(context);
    mTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    mTextView.setText(textName);
    mTextView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    mTextView.setX(x);
    mTextView.setY(y);
    mTextView.setTextSize(mTextView.getTextSize() * .15f);

    mContainer.addView(mTextView);
}
```

Comment: code!! we need to see the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this using an ViewTreeObserver. Android has every view at 0 on creation, but the ViewTreeObserver will allow you to get the locations after the views are drawn and aligned.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used GridView before so forgive me if I'm wrong, but could you try using setOnItemClickListener instead of setOnClickListener?